# Why Creator is needed inside Android Parceable?

Tags: android

I am trying to understand IPC in Android right now. I got to know about Parceable class in Android which does the job of marshalling of the object and a separate Parceable.Creator class which does the unmarshalling.

My question is why we need the separate class for the unmarshalling. Since the Parceable interface had the writeToParcel method, can't it also has the createFromParcel method?

Answer (score 0):

Posting what I feel might be an answer.

When the framework has to create the instance of the original class, it can't call instance method createFromParcel because there is no object present at that moment. So it needs some class level static field to get an instance creator, and that is where Parceable.Creator comes into picture.

Other solution might be to have the developers have a static createFromParcel in their class definition. But it separates this method from the Parceable interface since you can't have static methods in an interace.

Both the solution face the issue that their is no compile time check for whether the createFromParcel method is there or not.